# IRC Bot - Roulette Command

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to make a roulette command for my bot, and this is what I got so far.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data.Message.Replace("!roulette", ""))) {
    string _u = e.Data.Nick;
    string _b = e.Data.Message.Replace("!roulette", "");
    string[] _c = { "R", "B", "G", "Red", "Black", "Green",
                              "r", "b", "g", "redblack green" };
    Random _r = new Random();
    int rnum = _r.Next(0, 36); // 0-35
    if (_b.Contains(rnum.ToString()) && _b.Contains(_c.ToString())) {
        MessageHandler(conf.Nick, e.Data.Nick + " spins the wheel.. " + _b.ToString() + " " + (string)_c[rnum]  + "! We have a winner!", 8);
    } else {
        MessageHandler(conf.Nick, e.Data.Nick + " spins the wheel.. " + rnum.ToString() + " " + (string)_c[rnum] + "! You lose!", 8);
    }
}
```

I get the `Index outside the bounds of the array`. error, it's very strange for something not so complicated.

How would I fix this, would I ignore the array and go for a Dictionary or List<>?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I added that. I'm just a wee bit tired from being up all day trying to figure this one out.

Comment: `Random _r = new Random()` - you should use [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Also, `rnum = _r.Next(0, 36)` might have a bias (you have to watch the `Range` functions, which is what you are effectively calling). Can you build the range and then perform fair shuffle using [Fisher–Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)? Once the values are shuffled, take the first element as the selection. See "Securing a Shuffle Algorithm" on the crypto stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing `_c` array's element using the index `rnum`: `_c[rnum]`.
The`rnum` variable can have any integer value from the range `0 - 35`.
But the `_c` array has only `10` elements.

To fix it, limit the `rnum` variable to the range `0 - 9`:

```
int rnum = _r.Next(0, 10);
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks! Uh, sorry. Been a long week. Thanks, again!

Comment: Usually I would but it told me I couldn't accept till tomorrow.